# b2evolution to WordPress move & conversion

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, import

I have an old **b2evolution** blog (v1.10.2) over on a shared hosting account (w/ Plusmail).

I'm slowly migrating all my stuff to a new shared hosting account (w/ cPanel).

I want to export all blog data from my **b2evolution** and import into a brand new **WordPress** (v3.1) installation on the new server.

Both accounts have **MySQL** databases.

Most of the online stuff I'm reading about this have both blogs on the same server, the **b2e** blog version is much newer than mine, or the **WordPress** version is below 3.

I'm interested in anyone's constructive suggestions regarding the most painless way to do this.

**Thank-you!**

---

**EDIT**

I ended up using a WordPress CSV import plugin.  It's a little tedious preparing your CSV file but it's a rock solid method... you'll get exactly what you put in your spreadsheet imported instantly into WordPress without disturbing any existing posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up converting this blog.  The procedure below may seem like a lot of work but compared to the amount of time I spent looking for conversion scripts, it was a breeze.  I only had to export/import 70 posts and 114 comments so your mileage may vary.

1. Export the MySQL database from the old b2evolution blog.  You only need the table containing your posts (evo_posts).  If you want to mess with comments, you'll need that table too (evo_comments).  Export those as CSV files.
2. Download & install **CSV Importer plugin version 0.3.5 by dvkob** into your new WordPress v3.1 installation.  You do **not** need a fresh or empty WordPress blog... this import will not wipe out anything in WordPress... it will only adding more posts.  **Back-up your database to be safe.**  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/csv-importer/
3. Read the installation directions and follow them exactly.  At first you may think you only have to move a single php file into your WordPress directory.  In fact, you need to copy the plugin plus some stuff within a directory.
4. Read the documentation and look at the sample CSV files included with the plugin.  It shows what column headings you'll need and what each one means.
5. Open the CSV files you exported from the b2evolution SQL database in Excel.  There you can just delete all the unused columns and clean up your data if necessary.  Don't forget to rename the column headings as per the CSV plugin requirements.
6. OPTIONAL:  If you want to keep your comments intact and attached to each post, you'll need to match up the post ID from the comment table to the post ID in your new spreadsheet.  Each comment gets a new set of columns.  One post of mine had 21 comments so I had to add 63 columns... each comment got a username, content, and date/time but you can do this any way you wish.  Maybe write an Excel macro that handles this.
7. Once you get your data all cleaned up and formatted properly, save your Excel sheet as CSV (Windows) format.  I tried CSV (comma separated) and it failed to import.
8. Log into your WordPress Dashboard and your plugin is located under Tools as CSV Import.  Upload and hit import... that's it.  It took less than one second to add my 70 posts & comments.

**NOTES:**

Experiment with how this plugin creates your categories.  It seems that it wants to create all new categories as a child of "uncategorized".  Even if the category already exists on the top level as a sibling of "uncategorized", it still creates a duplicate as a child.  Not a big deal, easy to change the categories around in the WP Dashboard after import.

It's fussy about the CSV file format.  From Excel, make sure it's saved as CSV (Windows) format.

This may seem like a lot of work but the conversion alternatives caused me more trouble.  A day and a half jacking around with trying to get php convertors to work and trying to get an old skin to display the b2e as MT format as compared to only about an hour messing around in Excel...  this was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress install the plugins 'FeedWordPress' and optionally 'FeedWordPress Content Filter'.  Once configured, these will allow you to import your b2evolution posts direct from a RSS feed.  If your new WordPress users have matching emails as the old b2evolution users, the syndication will automatically assign the posts to them.

Comment: When I look at my b2evolution RSS Feed, I only see the last 4 posts even though I have nearly a hundred spanning back many years.  I select "all" and they stop short.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about getting a full feed from b2 as I've never used it, but this link might help: [link](http://blog.robertturrall.com/2011/01/07/importing-blog-entries-from-b2evolution-to-wordpress-3-x/)

Comment: Nothing is simple.  That link you posted looks great however, even when I download the RSS link, it's only the posts from that one page.  Even selecting ALL, I only get one page worth of posts and no comments.  Isn't there a way I can export the MySQL DB from the old server and import it to the new server and then do some kind of conversion?

Comment: There is a way to do that, but after a quick search, I found this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content#b2evolution and I think the moveable type method described might be easier.  The mysql method might work, but it says the script was a very old version of wordpress...

Comment: Thank-you... I am looking into the Movable Type method but, so far, all links to the required MT skins for b2evolution are dead.  Even the link on that Codex Wordpress page is no good.  I may have to create my own skin that conforms the data into the MT format.

Comment: Getting the skin to display the blog in Movable Type format is almost impossible so I gave up and started searching for conversion scripts again.  I installed WordPress version 2.1 in the same database as the old b2evolution blog on the old server.  I followed the directions on each of FOUR conversion scripts.  Two did nothing... blank page.  The other two simply wiped the new WP2 clean and gave some cryptic SQL syntax errors.  Now I can't even log into WP2 because the default admin was deleted by the convertor.  Probably need a convertor specific for my version of b2e.  Sigh.

Comment: This was a total no go...  http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/77488.aspx

Comment: I'm currently writing a script to export the content of an Elgg website in WordPress eXtended RSS export/import format.  If no-one else has solved your problem by the time I've got that working, I'll share it here on a GPL2 license so you can mod it for b2e.

Comment: I think the problem (universal convertor) hasn't been solved before because there are just too many variables.  Add to that all the huge differences between the various b2e versions.  Currently I'm importing the data into Wordpress via a CSV file.  It's a little tedious cleaning it all up in Excel but I wasted a day and a half trying to find and get these php conversion scripts to work... I wish I had just done the CSV import in the first place.  I'll post details after I finish.